# Dask.bag.map_partitions function receives a generator instead of a list

Tags: python, dask

I'm running a dask graph that looks something like this:

```
dask.bag.from_delayed(...).pluck(FEATURE_NAME).map(map_func).map_paritions(part_func)
```

And I'm having errors inside the execution of `part_func`, which turns out to be receiving generators instead of the bag items `map_func` is returning.

This felt like a graph optimization and I did find `lazify_task` and figured that it has something to do with the issue, as well as the `reify` graph nodes (which I couldn't find any documentation for).

While adding a `values = list(values)` line at the beginning of `part_func` seems to solve the issue at hand and gets my graph going, I feel like I may be missing something here about the internal implementation, optimization and/or approach towards building a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct that partitions within a dask bag are generally finite generators rather than lists.  This allows them to operate in less memory.

If you want to always interact with lists then you can, as you suggest, call `list` on the input or else call a `map_partitions(list)` call in between your operations.

Optimizations like `lazify_task` and `reify` are generally considered internal and can change at any time.  I don't recommend building applications that depend on them.  This is also partially why they have not been prioritized for documentation.